# Link generator from txt file

Tags: c#, hyperlink, generator

my english is not so good, but I need your help ;)
I would like to create simple c# form application which open txt file with data like this:

```
abc1
abc2
qwe1
```

and create me links like this:

```
http://website.com/q='abc1'`
http://website.com/q='abc2'`
http://website.com/q='qwe1'`
```

...

What should I use? Any ideas?

It should be buttons:

Open txt file -> Genereate links

on the left side I would like to have raw data from txt file and on the right side links generated.

Like on this picture:
[image]

Comment: Do you use WinForms or WPF or anything else? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i would suggest that you search for some beginner tutorials for windows forms and file input/output

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate | I know how open txt file and show the data in richbox, but don't know how to generate many links like this above ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use smth like this to read data from file and directly populate `RichTextBox`. Be sure to add proper validation per your requirements. If you want to re-use these links somewhere else you will need to add them to some application-level collection (ie `List<string>` or an array)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string line = null;

    OpenFileDialog loadfile = new OpenFileDialog();
    loadfile.Filter = ".txt (files txt)|*.txt";
    if (loadfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(loadfile.FileName))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                richTextBox1.AppendText(Uri.EscapeUriString(string.Format("http://website.com/q='{0}'", line)) + Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How to add this to button, generete and display links in right richbox?

Comment: edited answer - please take a look. Also you may want to read some articles as this are quite basic operations

Comment: Thank you very much. When I declare PathToYourFile like @"c:\test.txt" I have error Could not find file 'c:\test.txt'.
I dont understand - this file is in c:\ location ;/

Comment: what kind of application do you have? Desktop or Web? If the file exists, the only reason you can get error is lack of read permissions to "C:\" root.

Comment: I have this error when I debug my windows form application. Press the button1 and see error. || I wolud like to load file like this:

     

OpenFileDialog loadfile = new OpenFileDialog();
                    loadfile.Filter = "*.txt (files txt)|*.txt";
                    if (loadfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        ObjStream = new StreamReader(loadfile.FileName);
                        richbox1.Text = ObjStream.ReadToEnd();
                    }

Comment: edited answer, on my side it runs without exceptions.

Comment: This is what I meant. Thank you very much. Can I give you some points on this page somewhere? ;)
I'm really happy ;) ;)

Comment: If the answer helps you - you can upvote it. If it answers your question - accept it as answer. Details can be found in FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Today I started to play with the form and it does not work to end the way I wanted.
When the links are generated ' is not in the link. Is treated as text. When you open the browser, there is no 'and I care for him.
Link looks like: http://website.com/q='abc1 not http://website.com/q='abc1'
What should I change?

The second issue is the SPACE symbol between words.
For example 
abc cba

Link looks like:  http://website.com/q='abc
without cba ;/
How to change space into %20 while file is loading?

Thanks for your advice ;)

Comment: Most probably its `.txt` content that breaking last symbol apart. Changed code sample to avoid the issue

Comment: Works up nicely. The last thing. How to open all link in one browser tabs? For exaple I have 10 link and I wolud like to open all in one tab. I read about process.start, but I don't know how to use this with generated link.

Comment: this is completely different question and should be started as new topic

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the hyperlink label control. Its called LinkLabel and its in the winforms tool boox.